# ScrollTo element on validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, scrollto

I have a form that functions a lot like the one here 
http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/TthG9/

But since the form is a long one, I need the page to scroll smoothly to the first element with error, please take a look at my code :

```
highlight: function(label) {
        $(label).parent().find('.valid').each(function(){
            $('label[class^="valid"]').remove();       
        });
    },        
    success: function(label) {
        if(label.text('OK!').parent().find('.valid').html() == null) {
            label.removeClass('error').addClass('valid');  
        } else {
            label.remove();
        }
    },
     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "firstname")
            {
                error.insertAfter("lastname");
            }
            else
            {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        $.scrollTo(element, {duration: 750});
        }
    });


$("#frmsubmit").validate().form();
    $('label[class^="error"]:not(.valid)').remove();
```

So as you see I have to validate the form when the page loads to check mark the right fields (as per client requirements), so the scrollTo makes the page swings on load then swings on validation, I guess thats because it validates twice. How can I do it the right way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a trick but it will do, I set a global variable on top of a page, for example

```
var firstcheck = 0
```

inside the error handler

```
if (firstcheck == 1){
$.scrollTo(element, {duration: 750});
}
```

and after I called form() I set it to 1

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in many ways. Let's assume you want to scroll to the first error, then this will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-form').validate(
    {
        rules: {
            name: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            subject: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function(label) {
            $(label).parent().find('.valid').each(function(){
                $('label[class^="valid"]').remove(); 
                $(label).offset().top                
            });
        },        
        success: function(label) {
            if(label.text('OK!').parent().find('.valid').html() == null) {
                label.removeClass('error').addClass('valid');  
            } else {
                label.remove();
            }
        }        
    });
    $("#contact-form").validate().form();
    $('label[class^="error"]:not(.valid)').remove();
});
​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TthG9/6/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this different than the code that was there already?

Comment: and you removed the scrollTo, then how would this scroll smoothly ?